# Использование live - но без события

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите кто может! Я добавляю класс

```
$(".catItemExtraFields").addClass("testy");
```

После того как сработал фильтр на ajax, у меня jquery перестает работать за счет того что обновился элемент, да я понимаю есть функция `live` но она работает только в сочетании с событиями (hover, click) у меня нет События! 
мне просто необходимо что бы после работы фильтра ajax у меня просто класс был на месте !
- были варианты `setInterval` (плохой вариант)
- `livequery` (тоже самое что `live`) больше адаптации

гугл перелопатил, возможно не правильно ищу, но уже варианты у меня закончились

Comment: Приложите код(или кусок), чтобы стало понятнее. Вы и на словах не особо объясняете.

Comment: live устарел, если не ошибаюсь, еще где-то в начале десятилетия.

Comment: $(".catItemExtraFields").addClass("testy");

Comment: это и есть код , которой нужно реализовать после аякса! решение нашел и оно оказалось довольно простое., заказчик требовал очень срооочно закончить работу, потому не найти нельзя было !!!  
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$(".catItemExtraFields").addClass("testy");
});

Answer (score 1):

Можешь поместить нужный код в кастомное событие, которое при обновлении аякс будешь вызывать:

$(привязать_к_чему_угодно).trigger("имя_события");

И тут то уже можешь играться с live

Comment: Etki - да Лив работает на версии 1,4, для 1,7 уже должен быть on, я скоро буду эксперт с этой задачей в jquery! Спасибо большое Всем за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена. на всякий случай дублирую 
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { 
$(".catItemExtraFields").addClass("testy"); 
});